# Made tsc.exe use typeroots global npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, node-modules

In tsconfig.json there is settings for type definition: **typeRoots**

Default is something like

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

But this is using npm package installed localy (in project folder). What if I want make tsc.exe to use globally installed @types package>? Couldn't find any info about it. Or there is no way to do, except providing exact path of that global folder, smth like `"../../../../Users/Dim/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@types"` ?

Comment: good question, although [this article](https://hackernoon.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3) doesn't contain an answer, it's still worth reading. Also I think you should consider asking it on github, I did that myself